# ZendService\WindowsAzure with zf2

Tags: php, azure, zend-framework2, storage

I'm trying to install zendservice-windowsazure using composer. My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "pear",
        "url": "http://pear.php.net"
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }],
    "require": {
        "microsoft/windowsazure": "*",
        "zendframework/zendservice-windowsazure": "2.*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

According to the docs here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendservice.windows-azure.html

I can then create a new storage client like so:

```
$storageClient = new ZendService\WindowsAzure\Storage\Blob();
```

However, the source that composer installs is structured differently and appears to be a completely different version to the classes referenced in the documentation. For example, the above call, according to the source code that composer has installed, is actually:

```
$storageClient = new ZendService\WindowsAzure\Storage\Blob\Blob();
```

But then when listing blobs, the installed zendservice-windowsazure library calls:

```
Zend\Http\Client->request()
```

which is no longer a valid method in the Client class.

So it looks like either:

a) The wrong version of zendservice-windowsazure is being installed

b) The Zend documentation is incorrect

I'm inclined to think it's the first option, due to the invalid reference to

```
Zend\Http\Client->request()
```

If that's the case, how can I get the latest version of the module? Even the github repo for the module is the same version as that installed by composer, and therefore doesn't work as specified in the documentation.

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_WindowsAzure

Answer (score 0):

You can use old Windows Azure SDK for PHP 4.1.0 http://phpazure.codeplex.com/releases/view/78020. It works fine.